# Dropbox issue on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: boot, dropbox, drive

I have had my Dropbox account for several years. It  holds half terabyte of family photos and videos, important documents etc.
So, I really neds help to solve this situation: 
Dropbox insists on the local folder be located on the physical Home drive. I have, however succeded in moving that folder to another (2 TB) drive. This worked fine until recently, when the Dropbox app asked if I wanted to download the many thousand files in my cloud storage. Accidentally, I answered "Yes" instead of thew obvious denial. Before I discovered what was underway a lot of files were downloaded to a new folder on my Home drive so that my 256 GB SSD (large when I bought it - and expensive!)
Error messages told me that there was too little free space on my Home drive. I did not realise what had happened before the day, when my PC  stopped before the end of the boot sequence. since then it has not been able to complete booting.
All suggestions will be welcome!

Comment: What happens exactly when in the boot sequence? Error messages, etc.?

Comment: Onlym one error message during boot sequence: "Failed to start Apparmor initialization." Everything else is marked "OK". Boot ends witth the line: "Starting Hostname Service...r Dispatcher Service ......-0000:00: 14.0-usb1-1x2d10.service' for details". The same every time.

Comment: When I log in to the Dropbox homepage from another pc, all my files seem to have vanished. They can be seen on my phone, however - to my great  relief!